# HotChocolate returning null for DateTime?; Works fine for DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, hotchocolate

I am using .net 5 and HotChocolate. I have a call that is not returning any values for any fields that have a type of DateTime?, however works fine for DateTime. All fields have the same property type in SQL. This same call used to work, so not sure what's going on. I've searched Slack and GitHub, but haven't found anything. Looks like there was a [DateTime issue](https://github.com/ChilliCream/hotchocolate/pull/3347) that was fixed with 11.1. It doesn't seem to be same problem, but I upgraded anyhow. Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looking at the code that you linked for the datetime bug, it doesn't appear they have a case for serializing a `DateTime?` type? Have you tried using a `DateTime` instead?

Comment: You're not looking at the right object. The one you opened in the VS has the RecordID = 15 and the one you highlighted in the database has the RecordID = 261.

Answer (score 1):

long time no see

I am not sure if this is a HotChocolate problem, but lets find out.

The Issue you linked was indeed a change in V11.1, but looking at you screenshot it looks like the data is already missing on the backend. So I don't think it's this. At the point your debugger stopped, HotChocolate has not yet done much.

One thing I notice is the structure of the resolver. These middleware are order sensitive. Meaning, if they are in the wrong order they might not work properly.
I guess you added a ToListAsync() at the end of your resolver chain, because you would get a DB Context Disposed exception.
The correct order would be `UseDbContext(typeof(DbContext))=> UsePaging => UseProjection => UseSorting => UseFitlering`

Then you resolver could just be

```
public IQueryable<AVO> GetAVO([ScopedContext]KvoDbContext cox)=> ctx.AVOs
```

If you 'execute' the query already in you resolver (like with `ToListAsync()`) filtering, sorting, paging, etc. are applied in memory and projections do not have an effect.

Hope this helps. Either way, if you cannot figure it out, create a repro of the issue and [open an issue](https://github.com/ChilliCream/hotchocolate/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug_report.md) on the repo, so we can checkout out the behaviour.

Stay safe!

Comment: Well, Mr. Pascal, thank you for the info. That response has left me with much to work with. The ordering was great info; obviously had that wrong. Also, didn't know the execution would stop the projections. I changed my resolver as you suggested, but that leaves me with changes in the calling Angular project needed (no data being returned as currently designed after that resolver change). You have definitely given me something to begin with today that I am already now more confident about attacking thanks to you. Happy April Fools Day and stay safe back at you.

Comment: Ok, no need for repro. Finally figured it out....absolute human error. Head held in shame!! I still am very grateful for the education your provided. Very much appreciated, Pascal!